# How do I know what a participial phrase is within a sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, writing, participles, participial-phrases

Recently, I have realized that there are huge gaps in my knowledge in terms of grammar, so I have begun learning some of the basics. One thing I am trying to learn is the participial phrase. I understand that a participle is a verb that can be used as an adjective which is used to modify a word, phrase or clause, but sometimes it confuses me. For example, in the sentence...

'Leaping over the hurdles, Cindy appeared as graceful as an antelope."
I understand that 'Leaping over the hurdles" is the participial phrase since it modifies Cindy, but why is "appeared as graceful as an antelope' not a participial phrase aswell? From what I see, it describes Cindy being as graceful as an antelope, plus the word 'appeared' is a past participle isnt it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Leaping*** over the hurdles, Cindy **appeared** as graceful as an antelope.

Here, ***Leaping*** is a present participle. But ***appeared*** is not a past participle but a finite verb in the past tense, because ***appear*** is always an intransitive verb, i.e., it cannot have an object.

If you want to use an intransitive verb as a participle, it can rarely be in the form of a **past** participle unless it is used in a perfect construction, as in:

> *Cindy **has appeared** as graceful as an antelope.*

Therefore, if you want to use an intransitive verb as a participle outside a perfect construction, it should normally be in the form of a **present** participle only, as in:

> *Cindy **leaped** over the hurdles, **appearing** as graceful as an antelope.*

Here, ***leaped*** is finite verb in the past tense, and ***appearing*** is a **present** participle.